# Why can't all spectral lines be seen through a spectroscope?

Tags: spectroscopy

We did a lab where we looked at heated hydrogen, helium, argon, and neon gas through a handheld spectroscope. We had to track the colors of each line on a separate paper. However, for the argon, and neon, we had significantly fewer lines than what the actual emission spectrum shows. Our duty is to explain why. I've come up with 3 different theories, but my professor says they are incorrect.

1. The temperature was not high enough to cause the electrons to become excited enough to reach all of the possible energy levels, thus not producing all the lines for us.
2. Our eyesight simply isn't strong enough to view every single line released by the gases.
3. Certain spectral lines are more common than others, so we just happened to only view a select few lines as opposed to every single line.

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I've searched online and re-read through our textbooks and can't find anything like that mentioned, so I thought I might come here for some help. Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: What lines do you see?

Comment: Well, for example, in Helium, we only saw 5 lines (red, slightly less red, green, blue, purple).

Comment: Neon we were only able to really see 11 lines clear enough that we knew they were definitely there. 3 between red/orange, 2 yellow, 3 green, 1 blue, 1 indigo, 1 purple

Comment: Think about the resolution of your spectrometer

Comment: The hand held spectroscope has relatively poor resolving power. Here is the helium spectrum I acquired with one of my echelle spectrographs and a helium discharge tube: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/770049/313612. The most intense line is yellow, so if that is not what you saw, then you had poor results. Sorry!